# Adaptando código para LAravel , de preenchimento automático CEP

Tags: laravel, cep

Olá, estou tentando adaptar o código deste link:
http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2012/08/preenchimento-automatico-do-endereco-a-partir-do-cep/
para o Laravel 5.2 , sem sucesso.Funciona bem sem o framework, quanto aos "css" e "js" consigo importá-los para o laravel. Porém acredito que o problema está no arquivo "consulta_cep.php" que não carrega. Qualquer ajuda desde já agradeço. Obrigado, Valdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma mais simples possível, crie uma rota do tipo `controller` da seguinte maneira:

app\Http\routes.php

```
Route::controllers(
    [
        'cep' => 'CepController',
    ]
);
```

Então, crie o `controller`:

app\Http\Controllers\CepController.php

```
...

class CepController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(Request $request)
    {
        $results = simplexml_load_file("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=" . $request->get('cep'));

        return response()
            ->json($results);
    }

    ...

}

...
```

Se você visitar a rota http://seusite/cep?cep=13457091 vai ver algo do tipo:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#1470 ▼
    +"resultado": "1"
    +"resultado_txt": "sucesso - cep completo"
    +"uf": "SP"
    +"cidade": "Santa Bárbara D'Oeste"
    +"bairro": "Jardim Santa Rita de Cássia"
    +"tipo_logradouro": "Rua"
    +"logradouro": "João Ribeiro"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Criei um pacote para o Laravel para comunicar com o [CepAberto](http://cepaberto.com/), já faz toda a abstração dos métodos de consulta a cep, cidade, etc.

https://packagist.org/packages/robersonfaria/cepaberto

Você pode usar ele ou usar como inspiração para criar um pacote que consulte no [RepublicaVirtual](http://www.republicavirtual.com.br/)

Comment: utilizei o seu pacote, funciona mas por muitas vezes retorna erro 500 no servidor.

Comment: @WMomesso tem mais detalhes sobre o erro?
Observe no Cep Aberto eles possuem um limite de requisições por segundos e também diário, pode ser essa limitação que está te retornando 500, vou fazer testes pois deveria retornar um 403.
Caso não seja esse o seu problema me passa os dados da requisição que está te retornando erro para que eu possa analisar e tentar resolver o problema.

Comment: é um problema intermitente, pois as requisições que faço são para testar os formulários e tem um intervalo entre uma requisição e outra de pelo menos 2 horas, não tenho mais detalhes pois retorna apenas erro 500, já inclui a chave diretamente no arquivo achando que fosse problemas com o `env()`, mesmo assim acontece. utilizei a pouco um exemplo em php puro a pouco e tb está acontecendo, creio ser problemas no servidor do CepAberto mesmo.

Comment: @WMomesso veja ai, se conseguir algum detalhe a mais me passa que vejo, de qualquer forma vou fazer uns testes aqui para ver se ocorre comigo tbm, faz um tempo que não utilizo esse serviço.